# Вылетает ошибка: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:12345/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

Всем привет, я новичок и делаю по Ютубу простой чат, но столкнулся с проблемой:
вылетает вот такая ошибка в панеле разработчиков: "websocket_client.js:4 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:12345/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Вот мой код (Питон-файл):

```
import asyncio

import websocket

all_clients = []


async def send_message(message: str):
    for client in all_clients:
        await client.send(message)




async def new_client_connected(client_socket: websocket.WebSocketClientProtocol, path: str):
    print("New user connected")
    all_clients.append(client_socket)

    while True:
        new_message = await client_socket.recv()
        print("New message from a user", new_message)
        await send_message(message=new_message)

async def start_server():
    await websocket.serve(new_client_connected, "localhost", 12345)


if __name__=='__main__':
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event_loop.run_until_complete(start_server())
    event_loop.run_forever()
```

и (JS-файл):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){


    let websocketClient = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:12345");

    


}, false);
```

В строчке "let websocketClient = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:12345");" примечание "'websocketClient' is declared but its value is never read."

Comment: Вы уверены, что сервер создал сокет? У меня есть подозрение что нет. Обычно, создавая сокет, он помещается в переменную, а далее назначаются события типа onMessage, onConnect и т.д. а вы его как то создали в пустоту. Конечно, может в питоне это именно так и работает, однако я бы проверил сервер

Comment: Извините, но как можно проверить, создан ли сокет?